# loaders lifecycle in fragment

Tags: android

As a fragment goes thru it's lifecycle how does it affect the loader and how does the activity's lifecycle affect the loader?

when is a loader's onAbandon() called in a fragment and activity lifecycle context

Comment: Look into the documentation for FragmentManager and LoaderManager.  They're the ones that control the lifecycles of those components.